# Weird $key => $value comparison with PHP

Tags: php, foreach, key-value

I'm facing a weird issue with PHP. This simple example:

```
<?php
$array = array(
  'zero',
  'one',
  'id' => 'two'
);

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
  if ($key == "id") {
    echo "Key: ". $key .", value: ". $value ."\n";
  }
}
?>
```

should (imho) output this:

```
Key: id, value: two
```

But it outputs

```
Key: 0, value: zero
Key: id, value: two
```

How is this possible: `0 == "id"`?

Comment: Have you tried it with a strict comparison (`===`)?

Comment: It should give you "Key:0, value:zero..." though, is a typo there? http://codepad.org/qGfe1jNC .

Comment: Yeap typo, I'm correcting it right now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When *$key* is `0` and gets compared to the string "*id*", the string ("*id*") will be converted to an integer. Since "*id*" can't be turned into a valid integer that conversion will yield `0`, and the if statement becomes true.

Since you don't want the implicit conversion to happen between two types who aren't compatible use the more strict `===` version of `==`. `===` will see if the variables are of the same type and has the same exact value.

```
 if ($key === "id") {
   ...
 }
```

Documentation [PHP: Comparison Operators](http://se.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

---

**Examples**

```
var_dump (0         == (int)"id");
var_dump ((string)0 == "id");
var_dump (0        === "id");

var_dump (1.0 === 1);
```

output

```
bool(true)
bool(false)
bool(false)
bool(false) # be careful!
```

Answer (score 3):

You are being bitten by a process called [type juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php).

Try the following:

```
var_dump(0 == "id");
```

It will output `bool(true)`.

PHP is performing integer comparison, and when it attempts to convert the string `"id"` to an integer, the result is `0`. PHP will happily parse leading digits of a string and stop at the first non-numeric value, yielding integer `123` for strings like "123xyz". Because there are no leading digits in the string `"id"`, it is parsed as integer `0`.

The solution is to use `===`, which compares the value *and* type of two variables, without attempting to juggle the types of the operands.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
$key == 'id'
```

...will make PHP do integer comparison, since the lvalue is an integer.

If you're wondering why this:

```
if ($key) { ... }
```

...wouldn't give the same result, well it's because the lvalue here (while omitted) is boolean, equivalent to:

```
if (true == $key) { ... }
```

Therefore, PHP will attempt boolean comparison. You can use the `===` operator to force a type check.

You can refer to the [Type Comparison Tables](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) and the [Comparison Operators Table](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php).

Answer (score -1):

If you set the logic expression to take into account vartype

```
if (key === "id")
```

if will work. Just like @refp says.

Comment: Like the -1 with no explaination. Very educational.

Comment: Although I'm not the downvoter, I don't understand why you post an answer to point out another correct answer. Your post should have been a comment, which could be a likely reason for the downvote.

Comment: @Repox simple: the other correct answer was shorter before it got edited. So I kinda set mine to complement it. From now on I will encapsulate my answers hehehe.

Comment: I understand your reasoning, but still - you should have added it as a comment instead. Otherwise, other users will see this as an attempt to score easy reputation - and that will give the opposite effect ;-)

Comment: @Repox Indeed. Somehow, all I care about is: 1.) The vote leads to point it as a wrong post, which is not, hence is misleading; 2.) Wanted to solve the problem for the person asking, therefore I guessed I was answering. In fact, I find karma stuff barely interesting 'cause I don't see myself as a moderator in the future and all that... as I told you, looks like an answer must be self-contained in order to avoid being easy-reputation-gaining-like :) Will try to avoid commenting in an answer form now on. Thanks!